# Solr: using HTMLStripCharFilterFactory for the index field, still enables search on html tags

Tags: solr

I have used the HTMLStripCharFilterFactory for filtering html tags from the index, Below is my field type

```
<fieldType name="text_en_html" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100" >
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I have added the following json document from solr 4.2 admin interface

```
{"Id":"3242555","PostData":"Hello World <td width=100 nowrap align='right'> "}
```

According to the this https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory there should be only Hello world in the index, but even if I search for "width", it is showing results.

Also if I search for PostData:width or fq=PostData:width then it shows no results, but If I search for q=width , then its displaying the above inserted document.

So How do I prevent those tags from getting searched on ?

Comment: can you share the full schema? was is your default search field?

Comment: The problem was that the destination copyField was of different field type, which did not use the above charFilter, therefore when I searched in this field, it did not come up.

Comment: i am having a same issue. Did you get any solution?